# Excel Conditional Settings

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to set some conditional settings values but it seems like they aren't taking.
When I look at the excel document, they are defaulted.

green = 0.2
yellow = 0.1

they are showing as
green 0.8
yellow 0.6

```
private static void setIcon(Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet, string cell)
{
    try
    {
        Excel.IconSetCondition cfIconSet = (Excel.IconSetCondition)excelWorksheet.Range[cell, cell].FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition();
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[1].Icon = Excel.XlIcon.xlIconRedTrafficLight;

        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[2].Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[2].Icon = Excel.XlIcon.xlIconYellowTrafficLight;
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[2].Value = Convert.ToDouble(yellow);
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[2].Operator = (int)(Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual);

        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[3].Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[3].Value = Convert.ToDouble(green);
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[3].Icon = Excel.XlIcon.xlIconGreenTrafficLight;
        cfIconSet.IconCriteria[3].Operator = (int)(Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to call `excelWorksheet.Save` after you are done?

Comment: I save the workbook elsewhere in the code.

Comment: You're editing `cdIconSet` which is returned from the `AddIconSetCondition();` method, are you sure you don't need to put this IconSet into your worksheet somewhere?

Comment: Sorry that should have said i'm using excel 2010 interop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hvae used the following which is working.

```
var c = (Excel.IconSetCondition)excelWorksheet.get_Range(cell).FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition();
c.SetFirstPriority();
c.ShowIconOnly = false;
c.IconSet = book.IconSets[Excel.XlIconSet.xl3TrafficLights2];
var yellowIcon = c.IconCriteria[2];
yellowIcon.Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
yellowIcon.Value = Convert.ToDouble(yellow);
yellowIcon.Operator = (int)Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual;

var greenIcon = c.IconCriteria[3];
greenIcon.Type = Excel.XlConditionValueTypes.xlConditionValueNumber;
greenIcon.Value = Convert.ToDouble(green);
greenIcon.Operator = (int)Excel.XlFormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual;
```